# Parallel seam between drywall and plastered brick

Tags: drywall, framing, brick, plaster, crack

Most of the interior walling in my house that is under construction is using single skin brick with plaster.

In a few locations we require "cavity" doors and space has been left in the brickwork for the cavity, the intention is that the cavity will constructed using drywall (or potentially wedi board) quite possibly using a pc henderson "pocket door" kit for the framing.

One of the people I've come out to quote on the dooring has expressed concern about the join between the "plaster board" and the plastered brickwork - in his opinion it is likely a crack will keep forming here.

I was wondering firstly how valid a concern this really is, if done properly is it likely a crack will still form?

And secondly I was wondering what the best practice here would be.
The cavity system comes in different widths... Would it be better to try match the "finished wall thickness" of the cavity + plasterboard to the "finished wall thickness" of the brickwork + plaster, and then just do a thin skim to join them.

Or would it be better to rather have the cavity + plasterboard be approximately the same thickness as the brick and then apply a thick plaster over both to join them?

Any other tips to prevent hassles?

I've done a little explanation drawing (brick part not really to scale or anything like that, just to give an idea.
[image: dry wall cavity door joining onto single skin brick]

Picture of one of the brick walls with space for door cavity (roughly half of this will become a door opening) the other half will be framed for door to slide into.
[image: Door cavity]
(Sorry not the best picture, I'll try get a better one when next on site.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this question well without more details. A picture of the actual wall might be useful. It would depend on how the two sections of wall are built, and how they are fastened to one another.

Comment: @GregNickoloff added a photo, though not sure it will help all that much. At this point its just single skin brick, which will be plastered in future.
The portion into which the door will slide will likely use the "pc  henderson pocket door pro" kit though I'm still looking at other options, I can try adjust to whatever is best.
What I'm really looking for is best practice to do this - this sort of system is not that common here in za so its hard to get advice on it here.

Comment: The wood framing around the pocket door will expand and contract with the changing seasons much more than the brick will, so I'd think that would be a prime location for cracks in the surface plaster. Have you asked your contractor for a proposed solution?

Comment: I see. I would guess that the usual way to handle this is with a mesh or fibrous additives to the plaster. Where I'm at, I would think the "usual" way to do this would be to skin the walls and door with drywall and keep the seams away from the junction of the brick and sliding door.

Comment: @GregNickoloff Thanks that does make quite a bit of sense, just avoid the problem of having a join by skinning those walls entirely in drywall or similar, going to strongly consider that instead, will discuss with contractor. thanks.